# updating a window object(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have defined a global javascript variable openedWindow.

1.- Then within a function I have use the following code line.

```
var URL="myURL";
openedWindow = window.open(URL, "inventoryPage", "height=570, width=1000, scrollbars=yes, status=no, titlebar=no");
```

2.- That URL changes dynamically, so if the window is opened and the URL get changed.

```
var URL="otherURL";
openedWindow = window.open(URL, "inventoryPage", "height=570, width=1000, scrollbars=yes, status=no, titlebar=no");
```

A new window is opened with the "newURL" content.
I expected the second code line to updated the window that is already opened. I did not expect the code to open a new window.

If I do `openedWindow.close();`. Only the first window get closed.

What am I doing wrong?

I want the same window to get updated every time the URL change.

Comment: Could you add your code snippet.

Comment: To change the url, did you try `openedWindow.location=URL`?

Comment: Herr Derb: Your suggestion worked. I just needed to refresh my browser. I am sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Use `openedWindow.location.href="otherURL";`

Answer (score 1):

From the second time and after that you opened a window, invoke `window.open()` by specifying in the second argument : `_self`.
It will replace the current window.

```
openedWindow.open(URL, "_self", "height=570, width=1000, scrollbars=yes, status=no, titlebar=no");
```

or use :

```
openedWindow.location.href = URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the suggestions above worked, at the end I used the following code.

```
    if (typeof openedWindow == "undefined" || typeof openedWindow.location.href=="unknown")
        openedWindow = window.open(URL, "inventoryPage", "height=570, width=1000, scrollbars=yes, status=no, titlebar=no");
    else 
        openedWindow.location.href = URL;
```

I appreciate your answers guys!!